# requests failing on ElasticBeanStalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-sqs

I have a `java` project running on `AWS ElasticBeanStalk worker environment`, containing different crons which takes product ids from `SQS` and scrapes data from sites.
While I run the project on ElasticBeanStalk, the instance goes to warning state and sometimes gets degraded also. When I checked the causes,  I get this `error`: X % of the requests are failing with HTTP `5xx`. And due to this, the messages start going to `dead letter queue`.
When I `purge` the queue, instance again goes to `OK` state.

Attaching screenshots of health from EB console
[image: Enhanced health overview]
[image: Enhanced health overview]

I also checked the logs for health agent in  the health agent in /var/log/healthd/daemon.log
[image: daemon.log]

logs for /var/log/eb-cfn-init.log
[image]

I get this Command 01_restart_nginx failed error.
I am unable to figure out why this is happening

Comment: I assume this is an ElasticBeanstalk worker environment that sends SQS messages to your application via HTTP requests? All we know from the information you provided is that there is an error happening on the server when some messages are being sent to it. There's really not enough information here to help, you need to look at any and all logs on the server to find what the actual error message is.

Comment: If you used enhanced health reporting, it may be too detiled. As per [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/health-enhanced-rules.html) not all options in enhanced reporting should be used in all use-cases. The enhanced reporting should be customized to suit your needs. Maybe this is the case in your EB? Or change to basic health checks if you feel everything is ok.

Comment: Yes, you are right its an `ElasticBeanStalk worker` environment. Can you tell me exactly which logs to check?

Comment: Hey, I have edited the question. Can you please help. I am new to AWS.

Comment: Can anyone please help? I have added screenshots of the errors in logs